# JSONObject to String, different result in API 10 and API19

Tags: android

I have the following code for convert a JSONObject into a StringEntity that I will send via a HTTP post request. This is working fine on an actual device with KITKAT, but when I try in the emulator with API10, I got an error from the server.

```
JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
//filling the jsonRequest with data
System.out.println(jsonRequest.toString());
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonRequest.toString());
```

I have realize that the way JSONObject#toString works is different in API10 and API19 and that is why the server is returning a 500 error. This is what the println outputs:

API19

```
{"expenses":[{"category":"660","attachment":{"data":"\/9j\/4...
```

API10

```
{"expenses":[{"category":"660","attachment":"{data=\/9j\/4...
```

Note the equals symbol(=)  instead of colon (:) and the different position of the quotes (").

The json should look like

```
{
   "expenses":[
      {
         "category":"123",
         "attachment":{
            "data":"akcsdc...sdc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Why is this happening? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: which is your valid json? API 19 or API10 ?

Comment: As I wrote on the question: _This is working fine on an actual device with KITKAT, but when I try in the emulator with API10, I got an error from the server_

Comment: What is your error ? Where you have shown an error ?

Comment: Upvoted your question. This was such a pain for me to debug! Unfortunately I cannot use JSONObject as replacement for HashMap in my App because I need to send the objects back and forth (so it needs to be parcable/serializable). I think the only thing left for me to do is converting hashmap-->jsonobject and back :(

Comment: The folks at Google are simply incapable of doing anything correct or properly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found where the problem was, I was mapping the attachment object as a HashMap, I changed it to a JSONObject and now it works.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
Map<String, Object> attachmentMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
attahmentMap.put("data", dataString);
jsonObj.put("attachment", attachmentMap);
```

Changed to

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject attachmentJson = new JSONObject();
attachmentJson.put("data", dataString);
jsonObj.put("attachment", attachmentJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its going wrong when you convert it from HashMap. I used org.json.simple.JSONObject

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you elaborate on this more for other users?  Could you give a simple code example?